# How to do CRUD by linking two or more collections with a nodejs application using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am a beginner and would like to practice CRUD using nodejs and mongoDB (mongoose).
There is only one collection(employees) connected to the existing code, and we want to add another collection (eg, sensors).

Used by referring to [text](https://github.com/CodAffection/Node.js-Expess-MongoDB-CRUD)

my project folder

```
Node.js-Expess-MongoDB-CRUD-master
├─ project
│  ├─ controllers
│  │  ├─ employeeController.js
│  │  └─ sensorController.js
│  ├─ models
│  │  ├─ db.js
│  │  ├─ employee.model.js
│  │  └─ sensor.model.js
│  ├─ package-lock.json
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ server.js
│  └─ views
│     ├─ employee
│     │  ├─ addOrEdit.hbs
│     │  └─ list.hbs
│     ├─ layouts
│     │  └─ mainLayout.hbs
│     └─ sensor
│        ├─ addOrEdit.hbs
│        └─ list.hbs
└─ README.md
```

I added controllers/sensorController.js, models/sensor.model.js, views/sensor
and modified db.js

The code for the existing db.js file is as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/EmployeeDB', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, (err) => {
if (!err) { console.log('MongoDB Connection Succeeded.') }
    else { console.log('Error in DB connection : ' + err) }
});


require('./employee.model');
```

to

Changed as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/EmployeeDB'   , { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, (err) => {
if (!err) { console.log('MongoDB Connection Succeeded.') }
    else { console.log('Error in DB connection : ' + err) }
}        );
const EmployeeModel = conn.model('EmployeeModel', require('./employee.model'));
require('./employee.model');

const conn2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/SensorDB'   ,  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, (err) => {
if (!err) { console.log('MongoDB Connection Succeeded.') }
    else { console.log('Error in DB connection : ' + err) }
}  );
const SensorModel =conn2.model('SensorModel', require('./sensor.model'));

module.exports = {conn, EmployeeModel, conn2,SensorModel};
```

An error occurred as follows.

```
$ node server.js
Express server started at port : 3000
MongoDB Connection Succeeded.
MongoDB Connection Succeeded.
Error in retrieving employee list :MongooseError: Operation `employees.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
Error during record insertion : MongooseError: Operation `employees.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
Error in retrieving sensor list :MongooseError: Operation `sensors.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
Error during record insertion : MongooseError: Operation `sensors.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
Error during record insertion : MongooseError: Operation `sensors.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
Error during record insertion : MongooseError: Operation `sensors.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
Error in retrieving sensor list :MongooseError: Operation `sensors.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
```

I would appreciate it if you could answer my question

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are in conceptual confusion regarding collections and databases.

> Databases consist of one or more collections. Collections consist of
> one or more documents.

Maybe [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongodb-database-collection-and-document/) helps you to understand core concept of the MongoDB.

The problem is that you want to add a new collection but your code adds a new database.

If you want to add a new collection, just add the model. With this model, Mongoose will create a collection as soon as a new document is created. However, you can trigger it manually using [`createCollection`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.createCollection()) method if you wish.

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved it by adding a model as you said.